# how to style different tables ag-grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

**SITUATION #1:**
I have tables with different styles. When I go back to Table №1, Table №3, and Table №4 it takes styles from Table №2.
How can I apply styles to Table №2 for this table only? Is there a style prefix for different tables?

The global style for Table №1, Table №3, and Table №4 are called `grid-custom.css`:

```
.ag-root {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

For Table №2 I have local styles called `grid.css`:

```
.ag-root {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

return:

```
  return (
    <AgGridReact
      ref={ref}
      rowData={rowData}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
      rowHeight={60}
      headerHeight={50}
      onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRenderedSchoolTeam}
      onGridSizeChanged={() => onGridSizeChanged(ref)}
    />
   )
```

====================================================

The first situation is done. When just one id is applied to the table it works.

**SITUATION #2:**
I have global styles that apply to two tables. But after global styles, I need to apply a separate style for each table `border-radius`. In this case works just for #table1. Why? Same styles:

```
#table1 .ag-root {
  border-radius: 30px;
};

#table2 .ag-root {
  border-radius: 0;
};
```

Id for each table:

```
<div className="container-tables">
      <div id="table1">
        <TableOne
          rowData={rowDataOne}
          ...
        />
      </div>

      <div id="table2">
        <TableTwo
          rowData={rowDataTwo}
          ...
        />
      </div>
</div>
```

and same return for both:

```
return (
    <AgGridReact
      ref={ref}
      rowData={rowData}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
      rowHeight={60}
      headerHeight={50}
      onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRenderedSchoolTeam}
      onGridSizeChanged={() => onGridSizeChanged(ref)}
    />
   )
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Usama code updated

Comment: Are these grids on same page? You must be wrapping each grids inside `div` tag with `className` as shown [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/). Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 CSS files. Assuming, `global` file as which is applied on `App.js` for all components, and `local` for specific component. If you specifically want to apply css to Table 2 only then you need to assign `id` to div like this :

```
<div id="table2">
    <AgGridReact
      ref={ref}
      rowData={rowData}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
      rowHeight={60}
      headerHeight={50}
      onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRenderedSchoolTeam}
      onGridSizeChanged={() => onGridSizeChanged(ref)}
    />
</div>
```

Then inside CSS:

```
#table2 .ag-root {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #357a38;
}
```

Now, above CSS will only apply to `id` with table2 not on other tables

---

**UPDATE:**

The CSS is only getting applied on one table and not on other table. I can't figure it out why! But using 4th method: [CSS Modules](https://dev.to/salehmubashar/3-ways-to-add-css-in-react-js-336f), I managed to get the result.

Create a file named like `style.module.css`. Inside the file write your CSS

```
.table1 {
    background-color: #0575e6 !important;
}


.table2 {
    background-color: #357a38 !important;
}
```

Then import this file in your component like this:

```
import styles from './style.module.css'  //make sure the path is correct
```

Then, add `className` to your div

```
<div className={styles.table1} id="table1">
   ...
</div>
```

Same with `table2`, and you can remove `id` from divs as they are of no use now.

```
<div className={styles.table2}>
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: I added SITUATION #2. Can you check, please?

Comment: True, using inspect element I saw the css was not getting applied and was applying to one table only. From [this](https://dev.to/salehmubashar/3-ways-to-add-css-in-react-js-336f) blog I used 4th method using `style.module.css`. I still dont know why this behavior is occuring

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check if its working or not

Comment: with styles.module.css not possible to reach
 ` .ag-root {
    border-radius: 0 0 30px;
  }`
I found the way with classic css style. I will add to answer

Comment: I added the answer

Comment: I created a question: "How to add component on cell click in Ag-grid?". I would be grateful if you know the answer. Link to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72668577/how-to-add-component-on-cell-click-in-ag-grid

Answer (score 2):

I made folders for each table where I moved closer css styles. It looks:

```
-tables/
---tables.tsx
---tables-grid.css   <--- before tried to put styles for both tables `ag-root {border-radius: 0 or 30px}` here. It's doesn't work.
---table1/
------table1.tsx
------table1-grid.css   <---- now css closer `ag-root {border-radius: 30}`. Here it works!
---table2/
------table2.tsx
------table2-grid.css   <---- now css closer `ag-root {border-radius: 0}`.  Here it works!
```

Inside tables.tsx:

```
 return (
    <div className="tables-grid">
      <div id="table1" className="table1">
        <SchoolTeamTable
          rowData={rowData}
        />
      </div>
      <div id="table2" className="table2">
        <SeasonDetailsTable
          rowData={rowData}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Inside tables-grid.css:

```
.tables-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.table1 {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.table2 {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Inside table1.tsx and table2.tsx I import `table-grid*.css` as usualy `import './table1.grid.css';` and `import './table2.grid.css';`. and return same for both:

```
return (
    <AgGridReact
      ref={ref}
      rowData={rowData}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
      rowHeight={60}
      headerHeight={50}
      onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRenderedSchoolTeam}
      onGridSizeChanged={() => onGridSizeChanged(ref)}
    />
)
```

But for each table using a separate id style, in order to achieve `ag-root {border-radius: 30 or 0}`.

In `table1.grid.css` it looks:

```
#table1 .ag-root {
  border-radius: 30px;
};
```

In `table2.grid.css` it looks:

```
#table2 .ag-root {
  border-radius: 0px;
};
```