# How to add a child element when clicking the cell in Ag-grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to add an icon when clicking on the cell. When I click on a cell by using `teamFunction` in `cellRenderer` it shows info about the cell. But there is also the method `onCellClicked` which shows info about the clicked cell too. Both methods are clickable. I need to add an icon when clicking on the cell. I want to return div with icon to the selected cell:

[image: selected cell]

In the cell I need to add the child element:

```
 <div className="checked">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} color="green"/>
 </div>
```

In the teams array I have objects with info:

```
const teams = [
{
  gender: "boys"
  name: "High School Team"
  sport: "Volleyball"
  team_id: "12111"
},
{
  gender: "girls"
  name: "Middle School Team"
  sport: "Baseball"
  team_id: "12222"
},
{
  gender: "boys"
  name: "Students"
  sport: "Bowling"
  team_id: "12333"
},
]
```

Component:

```
  const onFirstDataRendered = useCallback(() => {
    ref.current.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }, []);

const teamFunction = (params) => {
    return (
      <div className="cell">
        <div>
          <div>{params.data.gender} {params.data.sport}</div>
          <div>{params.data.name}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      field: 'team',
      headerName: 'Team',
      cellRenderer: teamFunction,
      resizable: true,
      width: 100,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <AgGridReact
      ref={ref}
      rowData={teams}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
      rowHeight={60}
      headerHeight={50}
      onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
      onGridSizeChanged={() => onGridSizeChanged(ref)}
    />
```

Comment: where do you want to add the icon, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Usama Done. I added an image and updated the array with objects. If you need more information let me know

Comment: Please try like this: `<div className="cell"><div>{params.data.gender} {params.data.sport}</div><div className="checked"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} color="green"/></div><div>{params.data.name}</div></div>` within the `return` of `teamFunction` method.

Comment: @jsN00b in this case, the icon will be displayed in every cell. I need only on the selected cell.

Comment: How about adding checkbox column [ag-grid row selection](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/) ? Is this the right alternative of your problem?

Comment: @Usama I added Hook and updated the teamFunction. I will post the answer later

Comment: @Usama Answer posted

Answer (score 0):

I added Hook

```
const [selectedTeam, setSelectedTeam] = useState(null);
```

In teamFunction I control selectedTeam:

```
const teamFunction = (params) => {
   return (
      <div className={styles.cellStyles}>
        <div className={(selectedTeam !== params.data.team_id) ? styles.unSelectedTeam : null}>
          <div className={styles.boldText}>{params.data.gender}{params.data.sport}</div>
          <div>{params.data.name}</div>
        </div>
        {(selectedTeam === params.data.team_id) ? (
          <div className={styles.checked}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} color="#22EA72" style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} />
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

In columnDefs added onCellClicked:

```
onCellClicked: cellClicked,
```

cellClicked function controls the selected team :

```
const cellClicked = (params) => {
    setSelectedTeam(params.data.team_id);
};
```